# A curve with Lebesgue measure non zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, plane-curves

In this 
[Continuously Differentiable Curves in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and their Lebesgue Measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218584/continuously-differentiable-curves-in-mathbbrd-and-their-lebesgue-measur)
the domain of the curve is a compact set. I want know if the same answer holds for curves with non-compact image. For example I could take the curve(with dense image in $[-1,1]^2$) $$\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\cos(\sqrt2t)),$$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-compact, so it won't work.

Comment: Consider (a) the Monotone convergence theorem OR (b) that the countable union of null sets is null.